# DI in fluent validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am adding `HttpClient` to DI as follows in my **startup.cs**

```
    services.AddHttpClient("main", x =>
    {
        x.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44342/");
        x.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value"); 
    });
```

A little lower I add the validator to scope

`services.AddTransient<IValidator<Domain.Form.Form>, Shared.Validators.Form.Form>();`

The validator is defined as follows

```
public class Form : Base<Domain.Form.Form>
    {             
        public Form(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().MustAsync(async (name, cancellation) =>
            {
                var rtrn = true;

                rtrn = !bool.Parse(await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/forms/checkifnameexists?name=" + name));

                return rtrn;
            }).When(x => x.Id == default).WithMessage("A form with the same name already exists");
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is when the Validator hit, the `HttpClient` that is injected does not have the `BaseAddress` and headers set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how is Form initialized? Typically, when using services.AddHttpClient, you should then be injecting an `IHttpClientFactory` that allows you to get the named instance, which you are not doing here. As a result, I would expect a completely unrelated HttpClient to be used

Comment: is `class Form` the same thing as `Domain.Form.Form`? Why do you have a class sharing the same name as its namespace?

Comment: You created a "named HttpClient" but you haven't properly set your Form class up to receive a named HttpClient. You should be getting named client instances from an IHttpClientFactory. Make sure you [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-clients).

Comment: Also, _inheritance should not be abused for the sake of common-functionality_: whatever `Base` is, it looks like you're embuing a _single_ class with both data-transfer and data-validation responsibility - this seems unwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you are injecting a plain old `HttpClient` instance into `Form`, but you are registering a named client in your startup.

A [recommended approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#createclient) is to inject `IHttpClientFactory` into your instance, and then resolve your named client.

```
public class Form : Base<Domain.Form.Form>
{             
    public Form(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().MustAsync(async (name, cancellation) =>
        {
            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("main");
            var rtrn = true;

            rtrn = !bool.Parse(await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/forms/checkifnameexists?name=" + name));

            return rtrn;
        }).When(x => x.Id == default).WithMessage("A form with the same name already exists");
    }
}
```